# MS SQL trigger not inserting records for bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-server

One of the external application is inserting more than 40K records in the SQL Azure table.

I have a trigger to process all of the required rows which matches the column value for the unique column value for the distinct record

1. Whenever the 40K+ record in inserted the trigger is not able to fetch or trigger for all of the records and just getting 1 and 2 records sometimes.
2. In trigger how can I get distinct column value and order by.

3. inserting into temptables insert fewer columns only and random

How can i do batch processing from the trigger for the bulk insert

```sql
  /****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[PriceStagingInsertTrigger]    Script Date: 
    29/09/2020 13:46:24 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PriceStagingInsertTrigger] on [dbo]. 
    [SalesPriceStaging]
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS DECLARE @ItemNumber NVARCHAR(20),
           @applicablefromdate datetime,
           @partycodetype int

     SELECT @ItemNumber = ins.ITEMNUMBER FROM INSERTED ins;
     SELECT @applicablefromdate = ins.PRICEAPPLICABLEFROMDATE FROM INSERTED ins;
     SELECT @partycodetype = ins.PARTYCODETYPE FROM INSERTED ins;
     SELECT * into #temptables from inserted
     EXEC dbo.spSalesPriceStaging @ItemNumber,@applicablefromdate,@partycodetype

     PRINT 'Stored procedure spSalesPriceStaging executed and completed'
```

Comment: *"Whenever the 40K+ record in inserted the trigger is not able to fetch or trigger for all of the records and just getting 1 and 2 records sometimes."* Because your `TRIGGER` assumes an `INSERT` only ever effects 1 row. They can effect 1 or more... [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: Also, a `TRIGGER` should have as minimal impact on a DML statement as possible. Executing a Store Procedure is rarely minimal.

Comment: You can only store 1 value in the declared variables so your code will only insert 1 row to logmessage and exec once.

Comment: Personally, I would move the logic which executes the procedure else where. Have the trigger, if needed, log the data needed to a pooling table, and then have the stored procedure executed by a **different** process; likely a regular scheduled task. You will likely need to refactor your Procedure for a set based solution too, rather than process several scalar parameters.

Comment: @Larnu Hi , so you reckon i should store the value initially in the temp table and do the processing. As I am new to the SQL trigger so how can i ensure that I get all the records when there is a bulk insert ? is there any other better way to do rather then using the triggers ? , As my requirement is to process all the records as soon bulk insert happens for all the records interested

Comment: *"initially in the temp table"* A temporary table won't help you, as soon as the `TRIGGER` completes the table would be dropped and the scheduled task would error, due to the object not existing (plus that would be run in a completely separate scope). You need a permanent table as the pooling table.

Comment: The question is : do you need absolutely a synchronous process or can you accept that the process treats all the rows as soon as possible ?

Comment: @SQLpro as soon records are inserted in should process all of the records , as there are columns which needs to be grouped into single set of records and all set of records needs to be processed for further processing

Answer (score 1):

The (BAD) solution is :

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[PriceStagingInsertTrigger] 
ON [dbo].[SalesPriceStaging]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ItemNumber NVARCHAR(20),
           @applicablefromdate datetime,
           @partycodetype int;

DECLARE C CURSOR 
FOR 
   SELECT ITEMNUMBER, PRICEAPPLICABLEFROMDATE, PARTYCODETYPE 
   FROM inserted;
OPEN C;
FETCH C INTO @ItemNumber, @applicablefromdate, @partycodetype;
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
   EXEC dbo.spSalesPriceStaging @ItemNumber,@applicablefromdate,@partycodetype;
   FETCH C INTO @ItemNumber, @applicablefromdate, @partycodetype;
END;
CLOSE C;
DEALLOCATE C;
GO
```

As they say, trigger in SQL Server have a set based logic and fires only one time even if there is 3657435435143213213 rows that are inserted.

The presence of a variable in the code is generally a pattern a bad code design....